# Tekton, npm ci, and "npm ERR! EMFILE: too many open files, open '/root/.npm/_cacache/"

Tags: npm, openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm using an incredibly simple pipeline to build my angular App. I run it on an openshift cluster.

these are the two tasks:

```
  tasks:
    - name: fetch-source
      params:
        - name: url
          value: $(params.repo-url)
        - name: revision
          value: feature/tekton
      taskRef:
        kind: ClusterTask
        name: git-clone
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: shared-data
    - name: build-push
      params:
        - name: IMAGE
          value: $(params.image-reference)
        - name: DOCKERFILE
          value: $(params.containerfile-path)
        - name: CONTEXT
          value: $(params.context-dir-path)
      runAfter:
        - fetch-source
      taskRef:
        kind: ClusterTask
        name: buildah
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: shared-data
```

I'm trying to build this container file:

```
FROM node:latest as builder

USER root
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

RUN chown -R root /usr/local/app

RUN npm ci

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server
FROM nginx:latest
[...]
```

The command `npm ci` fails with the error:

```
npm ERR! code EMFILE
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/d8/c0/7503a3169361b6a2c8813bf0eddb92eed6417987f616accf18698f2b71f4
npm ERR! errno -24
npm ERR! EMFILE: too many open files, open '/root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/d8/c0/7503a3169361b6a2c8813bf0eddb92eed6417987f616accf18698f2b71f4'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-03-27T13_42_33_018Z-debug-0.log
subprocess exited with status 232
subprocess exited with status 232
Error: building at STEP "RUN npm ci": exit status 232
```

In my understanding NPM tries to open too many files and hits the ulimit of the container (1024). The Build config that is doing the same operation has not problem and I don't know how that can be possible. I suspect the difference is that the build that is working is executed in a privileged context but i don't know if it's safe to do the same with tekton tasks.

Any idea on were the problem could be?